# How to determine which trigger executed background task in Windows 8?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

I've got a problem with background task in WinRT application. I register task with two triggers

```
var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder
        {
            Name = "MyTask",
            TaskEntryPoint = "Task.MyTask"
        };
        builder.SetTrigger(new TimeTrigger(60, false));
        builder.Register();
```

Then i do almost the same:

```
builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder
        {
            Name = "MyTask",
            TaskEntryPoint = "Task.MyTask"
        };
        builder.SetTrigger(new SystemTrigger(SystemTriggerType.InternetAvailable, false));
        builder.Register();
```

and in my background task logic i want to determine, which trigger executed background task. `taskInstance.TriggerDetails == null`
this is always true, when task starts working.

please, help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not create `TimeTask` and `InternetAvailableTask` classes?

Comment: i did exactly the same... but there is a lot of same logic in this tasks and only few operations differ. This is ugly(
But if there is only one solution... so let it be.

Comment: `public class TimeTask : StandardTask {}`?

Comment: Have you try taskInstance.Task.Name? This way, you will only need two BackgroundTaskBuilder instances, not to IBackgroundTask implementations.